# GridView.minHeight does not work for small item counts

Tags: java, android, gridview

I use this markup:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvBlock0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/solitude"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        tools:layout_height="120dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_block"/>
```

If I have only 3 items (40dp height per row) I have 2 rows and 80dp height.
If I change `android:layout_height=120dp`, I have 120dp height as expected.

But I want use only minHeight. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `GridView` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/GridView.java), it seems that it does not support `minHeight` attribute.

You can fix it by one of the following:

**1)** Create a `MinHeightGridView` custom class that **extends** `GridView` and fix the issue by adding the following override code for example:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    // After GridView measured everything, see if height needs update
    int desiredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    desiredHeight = Math.max(desiredHeight, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), desiredHeight);
}
```

**2)** Encapsulate the `GridView` inside a container view - The container view will have a `minHeight`. Make sure to set background and gravity as needed on the container view, for example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/solitude"
    android:minHeight="120dp">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvBlock0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        tools:layout_height="120dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_block"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.
Keep the `GridView` in a parent and set the `minHeight` of that parent to "120dp". Then as for the inner `GridView` use `"match_parent"` for the height attribute.